# OpenERP Events Organisation Web Integration

Tags: events, integration, organization, odoo

Does anybody knows how exactly can OpenERP's [Events Organisation module](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/features/events_organisation.html) be integrated with a website for event registration? Basically, a registration form on a website should be able to send information to the module, but I have no experience with this, neither with OpenERP or its web integration, but we would like to implement it. For instance, the module information says that it helps on getting the payments -the registration process should charge participants' credit cards- but it doesn't says anything on what exactly that means and how should it be done.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to manage event registrations as part of your web site, I think `OpenERP` is probably overkill. It's a full ERP system for running your business, so there's a lot to learn.

However, if you want to try it out, I suggest you start by [getting a trial subscription](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/1/1_0_Subscribe_Start/index.html) and reading through [the guided tour](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/1/1_2_Guided_Tour/index.html). I haven't tried the events module, so I can't tell you how useful it is.

To integrate `OpenERP` with your web site, you would probably make `XML-RPC` calls from your web server to the `OpenERP` server. See the [developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html) for details.